# Multiple gathering in R to create tidy dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a complicated untidy dataset which a dummy version of can be replicated below.

```
studentID <- seq(1:250)
score2018 <- runif(250)
score2019 <- runif(250)
score2020 <- runif(250)
payment2018 <- runif(250, min=10000, max=12000)
payment2019 <- runif(250, min=11000, max=13000)
payment2020 <- runif(250, min=12000, max=14000)
attendance2018 <- runif(250, min=0.75, max=1)
attendance2019 <- runif(250, min=0.75, max=1)
attendance2020 <- runif(250, min=0.75, max=1)

untidy_df <- data.frame(studentID, score2018, score2019, score2020, payment2018, payment2019, payment2020, attendance2018, attendance2019, attendance2020)
```

I would like to gather this data frame so that we only have 5 columns: studentID, year, score, payment, attendance. I know how to gather at a basic level, but I have 3 sets to gather here, and I can't see how to do this in one go.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

With `tidyr` you can use `pivot_longer`:

```
library(tidyr)

untidy_df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -studentID, names_to = c(".value", "year"), names_pattern = "(\\w+)(\\d{4})")
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 750 x 5
   studentID year    score payment attendance
       <int> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1         1 2018  0.432    10762.      0.786
 2         1 2019  0.948    11340.      0.909
 3         1 2020  0.122    12837.      0.944
 4         2 2018  0.422    11515.      0.950
 5         2 2019  0.0639   12968.      0.828
 6         2 2020  0.611    13645.      0.901
 7         3 2018  0.489    11281.      0.784
 8         3 2019  0.00337  12250.      0.753
 9         3 2020  0.711    12898.      0.803
10         4 2018  0.0596   10526.      0.842
```

Comment: I always forget the `.value` sentinel. Have my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Using pure R:

```
tidy_df <- reshape(untidy_df, direction="long", idvar="studentID", varying=2:10, sep="")
head(tidy_df)

       studentID time      score  payment attendance
1.2018         1 2018 0.86743970 10995.45  0.9473540
2.2018         2 2018 0.53204701 11152.74  0.8167776
3.2018         3 2018 0.90072918 10631.06  0.9335316
4.2018         4 2018 0.89154492 11889.23  0.9098399
5.2018         5 2018 0.06320442 10973.20  0.8118909
6.2018         6 2018 0.67519166 11751.67  0.8328860
```

If you want "year" instead of the default "time", add `timevar="year"`

Answer (score 1):

We could try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

untidy_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -studentID) %>% 
  separate(col = name, sep = "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)", into = c("measure", "year")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = measure, values_from = value )
```

Which returns:

> ```
>   studentID year  score payment attendance
>       <int> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
> 1         1 2018  0.807  10179.      0.974
> 2         1 2019  0.599  11601.      0.785
> 3         1 2020  0.515  12347.      0.760
> 4         2 2018  0.474  11154.      0.983
> 5         2 2019  0.409  11682.      0.864
> 6         2 2020  0.688  13756.      0.812
> 7         3 2018  0.509  11746.      0.870
> 8         3 2019  0.867  12851.      0.801
> 9         3 2020  0.878  12710.      0.955
> 10         4 2018  0.621  11165.      0.975
> ```

Comment: It's crazy that people can come up with the same approach within 20 seconds of each other.

Comment: Yea, many proficient tidyr users here... and as we can see my solution isn't even the most straight forward ;)